# SQL partially works but needs a few WHERE clauses - I think

Tags: mysql

How can I change this SQL to do the following:

1. If user is not in table, add them. [THIS PART WORKS]
2. If user IS in table AND `favourite_active = 0` change it to `favourite_active = 1`.
3. If user is in table AND `favourite_active = 1` change it to `favourite_active = 0`.

I need to add in WHERE clauses I think.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_favourites WHERE (user_id = '$who' AND favourite_id = '$usernum' AND favourite_active = '1')");

// if user does not exist in favourites, add them
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
    {
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_favourites (user_id, favourite_id, favourite_active) VALUES ('$who', '$usernum', '1')");
        echo"You have added this user as a favourite";
    } 

// if user does exist and favourite_active = 1 change to 0
    else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_favourites SET favourite_active='0' WHERE user_id='$who' AND favourite_id='$usernum'"); 
        echo"You have removed this user as a favourite";
    }

// if user does NOT exist and favourite_active = 0 change to 1
    else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_favourites SET favourite_active='1' WHERE user_id='$who' AND favourite_id='$usernum'"); 
        echo"You have removed this user as a favourite";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two `else` clauses in an IF. And you can't do the `UPDATE` in two separate queries, because the second one will simply undo the first one. Use the following query:

```
UPDATE tbl_favourites SET favourite_active = NOT favourite_active WHERE user_id = '$who' and `favourite_id = '$usernum'
```

I'm also not sure that the first part, which you say works, really works. Your `SELECT` query looks specifically for `favourite_active = 1`. If the user already exists with `favourite_active = 0`, you'll try to `INSERT` them. Is that really what you want? Maybe you should remove `AND favourite_active = '1'`.

If `user_id` and `favourite_id` form a unique index on the table, you can do the entire thing in a single query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_favourites (user_id, favourite_id, favourite_active)
VALUES ('$who', '$usernum', '1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE favourite_active = NOT favourite_active
```

Comment: I've used that last section of code and it does work once first clicked - the details go into the table. But once executed again, the information is just re-entered into the table

Comment: Just on the main table id i think

Comment: For the second code to work, you need to add a unique index on these columns in the `tbl_favourites` table. I'm assuming they're supposed to be unique.